# protractor can not recognize css web element which java and selenium can

Tags: protractor

Hi I'm getting error when trying to click on the css web element. Error:

```
- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .fuse-search-bar-expander)
```

It is angular web page and exactly the same element I can locate in java with selenium like:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".fuse-search-bar-expander")).click();
```

I can not do it with protractor in javascript (due to error). 
My code:

```
await element(by.css(".fuse-search-bar-expander")).click();
```

Already tried options like, without luck to find that element.

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = [ true | false ];
```

Comment: Can you give the HTML snippet under question.

Comment: Try add a long sleep before the `click()`, to see the issue gone or not.

Comment: this is too broad, can you provide a little more context? how the html element looks, where/when are you using the `.click()`... etc

Comment: And also please include your protractor version and configuration file

Answer (score 0):

`await` should not be used.

Try with `element(by.css(".fuse-search-bar-expander")).click();`. If your page takes time to load add some wait.

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = [ true | false ]; // Is now deprecated
```

use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true|false); //makes protractor wait till all the http request are completed.`

if it does not work add your `testfile` and your `html`of the locator

Hope it helps you

Comment: why `await` should not be used? if the locator is followed by a `.click();` then `await` should be there, if it's inside an `async` function, of course.

Comment: Any specific or justification as to why await should not be used?

Comment: @JoaquinCasco it is recommended to use as below
`const ele = element(by.css(".fuse-search-bar-expander"));
await ele.click();`. Because using `await` may cause unexpected failures in your test run

Comment: as per your example there is no difference which syntax to use as long as config has `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false`